# How to get the x-auth value inside a response header with React?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

just ran into a new problem, my token is passed from the server by the response header as 'x-auth'

[image]

Seems like react can't let me access this value by using response.headers.x-auth,

if I do `console.log(response.headers)`, it does show

```
{content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8", x-auth: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1Y…jE0fQ.vDdRlqqgmdhJgy9g20QnbZ6HVSkJv_ZXdeOdeAHwBhw"}
```

but if I use `console.log(response.headers.x-auth)`, it will get 'undefined', my assumption is that it treats x-auth as a calculation as x - auth, not a property.

How can I fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access an object's property with a dash via dot notation (because the dash will be interpreted as a minus sign), but you can do so with bracket notation:

```
response.headers['x-auth']
```